# Programmatically set image to UIImageView with Xcode 6.1/Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to set UIImageView programmatically in Xcode 6.1:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bgImage: UIImageView!

var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"afternoon")!
bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
bgImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
view.addSubview(bgImage)
```

But Xcode is saying "expected declaration" with `bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)`  Image `"afternoon"`is a PNG, and my understanding is PNG does not need an extension in XCode 6.1.

Also tried just `bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "afternoon")`, but still get:

[image]

**UPDATE**

OK, I have put the code to update `UIImageView` into the `viewDidLoad` function, but `UIImageView` is still not showing the image (which exists in the base directory as afternoon.png):

```
@IBOutlet weak var bgImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    updateTime()
    var timer = NSTimer()
    let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"afternoon")!
    bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
}
```

Comment: You need to put that code into a function. I'd put it in viewDidLoad().

Comment: Since you declared it as an outlet, have you tried simply assigning the image instead of re-initializing it? instead of `bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)` just using `bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "afternoon")`?

Comment: See updated OP...Very new to XCode...very familiar with JavaScript, jQuery, PHP etc

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Since you have your bgImage assigned and linked as an IBOutlet, there is no need to initialize it as a UIImageView... instead all you need to do is set the image property like `bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "afternoon")`. After running this code, the image appeared fine since it was already assigned using the outlet.

[image]

However, if it wasn't an outlet and you didn't have it already connected to a UIImageView object on a storyboard/xib file, then you could so something like the following...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var bgImage: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "afternoon")!
        bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
        bgImage!.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200)
        self.view.addSubview(bgImage!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 52):

In xcode 8 you can directly choose image from the selection window (NEW)...

- You just need to type - "image" and you will get a suggestion box
  then select -"Image Literal" from list (see in attached picture)  and
- then tap on the square you will be able to see all images(see in
  second attached picture) which are in your image assets... or select 
  other image from there.

[image]

- Now tap on square box - (You will see that square box after selecting
  above option)

[image]

Comment: Wow, first time seeing something like that in an IDE, looks pretty cool in my code now

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy. Take care mate.

Comment: My Xcode version is 14.2. What am I missing that when I type *image* that **Literal** option does not appears in the list?

Answer (score 11):

OK, got it working with this (creating the UIImageView programmatically):

```
var imageViewObject :UIImageView

imageViewObject = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600))

imageViewObject.image = UIImage(named:"afternoon")

self.view.addSubview(imageViewObject)

self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewObject)
```

Answer (score 10):

How about this;

```
myImageView.image=UIImage(named: "image_1")
```

where image_1 is within the assets folder as image_1.**png**.

This worked for me since i'm using a switch case to display an image slide.

Answer (score 5):

This code is in the wrong place:

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"afternoon")!
bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
bgImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
view.addSubview(bgImage)
```

You must place it inside a function. I recommend moving it inside the `viewDidLoad` function.

In general, the only code you can add within the class that's not inside of a function are variable declarations like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bgImage: UIImageView!
```

Comment: ..thanks for your help, but UIImageView is still not showing the image...see updated OP

Answer (score 3):

With swift syntax this worked for me :

```
    let leftImageView = UIImageView()
    leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "email")

    let leftView = UIView()
    leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)

    leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    leftImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)
    userNameTextField.leftViewMode = .always
    userNameTextField.leftView = leftView
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4, if the image is returned as nil.

Click on image, on the right hand side (Utilities)  -> Check Target Membership

Comment: My UIImage was returning nil, for the reason you mentioned, 10x

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it the way you showed in your question, this is a way to do it inline

```
class YourClass: UIViewController{

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  //other IBOutlets

  //THIS is how you declare a UIImageView inline
  let placeholderImage : UIImageView = {
        let placeholderImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "nophoto"))
        placeholderImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return placeholderImage
    }()

   var someVariable: String!
   var someOtherVariable: Int!

   func someMethod(){
      //method code
   }

   //and so on
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to drag and drop an `ImageView`, create the outlet action, link it, and provide an image (Xcode is going to look in your `assets` folder for the name you provided (here: "toronto"))

In `yourProject/ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "toronto")
    }
}
```