# How to load specific image from assets with Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, size, assets

I'm new to Swift and I want to load a special image from assets. For example I have:

```
image 1 for iphone 4s = green-square@2x.png
image 2 for iphone 5/5s = green-square-Retina@2x.png
image 3 for iphone 6s = green-square@3x.png
```

and I want to load for iphone 6 a specific image like

```
self.GSquare = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "./Images.xcassets/green-square-Retina@2x.png")
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You only need it to be `"green-square-Retina"`.

Comment: no it dosent load im using 3 image with different size

Comment: What is the name of your Image in the Images.xcassets?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You cannot load images directly with `@2x` or `@3x`, system selects appropriate image automatically, just specify the name using `UIImage`:

```
UIImage(named: "green-square-Retina")
```

Comment: "green-square-Retina" doesn't load

Comment: Make sure that it is there and have `png` extension

Comment: yes its there and it load automaticaly for iphone 5/5s but i want to use it also for iphone 6 because iphone 6 load iphone 4s image size, so i have done a detection for the current screen size so i can know that the current devise used is iphone 6 and then i load the retina image

Comment: It is correct behavior, `@3x` loads only for iPhone 6 Plus. If you wish to force load other image, determine device type in runtime and use different image with another name, but this is not good approach

Comment: that's why i want to know if there is a possiblilty to do it directly because if i do for each image another one my application will get heavier

Comment: You are following wrong approach in general. You may not use `Assets` and give each image personal name like `imageName-2x` and manually manage image loading. But it would be better to use it as intended

Comment: Thank you i will manage manually the iphone 6 only

Answer (score 88):

Since swift 3.0 there is more convenient way: #imageLiterals [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39988566/751932) is text example. And below animated example from [here](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Adding-Image-Assets):

[image]

Comment: The single answer that provides the good practice!

Comment: as for May 2019, you have to double click on the symbol inserted by Image Literal option. This will open your assets list

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but using #imageLiteral makes code totally unreadable

Comment: And in 2023 and Xcode 15.0.1, the imageLiteral is **literal**ly broken. Classic Xcode developer experience.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily pick image from asset without `UIImage(named: "green-square-Retina")`.

Instead use the image object directly from bundle.
Start typing the image name and you will get suggestions with actual image from bundle. It is advisable practice and less prone to error.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39746722/5949670) Stackoverflow answer for reference.