# Why can't I use the new inline #imageLiteral syntax in Xcode 8? "Expected expression in return result"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to use the new `#imageLiteral` inline image assignment from your assets folder in Xcode 8, where instead of the whole `UIImage(named: "")` syntax it's just the image displayed, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610994/xcode-8-image-completion).

But when I do, I get the error "Expected expression in return result" when it's a function.

Here's a simple example:

```
func img() -> UIImage {
    return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "small-checkmark")
}
```

Where in Xcode it displays the `small-checkmark` as would be expected, but it won't compile due to the above error. Everything is autocompleted for me, the file is in the assets folder (a PDF). I don't understand what's going wrong. If I just return `UIImage()` it compiles fine.

What should I be doing?

Comment: You shouldn't type `#imageLiteral..` just type `return small-checkmark` and Xcode should recognise the completion as you type `sma...`

Comment: @RashwanL It isn't

Comment: Okey @DougSmith, remove it. Have you med sure that you double click the image from the intellisense? Your code compiles fine for me.

Comment: @RashwanL Yeah I made sure of that

Comment: @Paulw11 The image literal is what Xcode has behind the scenes, I'm not typing it.

Comment: Sorry, can't help then. your code works for me in a test app. You could try splitting the line in two; assign the,image via a `let` and return the constant

Comment: @Paulw11, same here works both with an image and a PDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check Swift Version.

```
Build Settings > Use Legacy Swift Language Version = NO
```

Image Literal is only supported on Swift3.0, not Swift2.3.

Comment: Ah that's the issue I'm still on 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

For all having the same problem with Xcode 10 / Swift 4.2 -> Unfortunately, this feature (imageLiterals, auto completion ) was deprecated in its previous form.

But there is new way to use imageLiterals -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52523111/3143890