# Implementing pixel-perfect background images in different orientations

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm developing a game in `Swift` (not `Spritekit`) and I'm having some difficulty creating a background image that works in every device orientation.

I see an `XCode` feature called `asset catalog` for defining the launch screen images, and I wonder if we can do something similar to define the device's background images?

Just like I said, I want to create a group of images to every device and orientation and create a image set or `asset catalog`, but i don't know how to do that. Has anyone here already done something like this?

*I know the concept of `@2x` and `@3x` images, but how can i implement images like that to other orientations?

**Update 1**: i posted one picture to help
[[image: asset catalog for Launch Screen Images[1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new image to your Asset catalogue:
Activate iPhone and iPad and choose the size classes you need:

[image]

Comment: 's Nice! I think this is what i need. There's any place with "legends" for the [**] symbols?

Comment: Just mark an image. There is an explanation shown at the top like 'Universal 1x Regular Height'

Answer (score 1):

When you edit storyboard, you will see `wAny hAny` at the bottom. There you could choose orientation and device type. After choosing you do anything you want, and it would be only in that orientation and that device type.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: But i can set a specific image to a specific size class?

Comment: You can add specific ImageView for specific size class

Comment: i already tried that, but it keeps pilling the ImageViews. For example, i create an view in the wCompact / hRegular and it didn't appear in the other settings, fine. But when i create another view in wCompact / hAny, the view also appear in the wCompact/hRegular configuration.

Comment: It should, that's how size classes are made.
Maybe you could do this with some code?

Comment: Did you have any tutorial to indicate? I'm really lost in this subject =/

Comment: @ZéMoreira Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039140/programmatically-set-image-to-uiimageview-with-xcode-6-1-swift) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796545/getting-device-orientation-in-swift). At first you should get device model, then you should get device orientation. But if device orientation can be changed you need listener for this.And all these should change image for view.

Comment: Thanks, @stek29. So the only way to do that is through code? I thing that it can be done through the storyboard and asset catalog too.

Comment: Only Size Classes then, but you've said that it's not suitable for you.

Comment: it's suitable, i just don't know how is the best way to do it =/